# Conexión a servicio http con swift

Tags: swift

Hola estoy tratando de conectarme a un web service http que esta corriendo en un servidor local, sin embargo me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tendrás que conectarte a la red donde estas exponiendo el servico localmente, luego en el info.plist debera agregar el siguiente path

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

- Es posible también que usted arme correctamente su petición, si puede describir en los comentarios que esta utilizando podría ayudarle con un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Error = 1001 "The request timed out"

Este mensaje de error indica que no se recibió un mensaje de respuesta del dispositivo de destino en un período de tiempo razonable. Suponiendo que la conectividad de red está bien, esto suele ser un indicador de que el dispositivo de destino no está conectado a la red, está apagado o no está configurado correctamente.
También podría significar que la request se está enviando a una dirección IP no válida.

De todas formas **tu pregunta está muy mal formulada**, ni siquiera has explicado el código que estás utilizando, si no eres mas especifico nadie te va a ayudar.